# Definition of locally X spaces and existence of open X neighbourhoods

Tags: general-topology, definition

I'm having some trouble with the definition of locally X spaces (connected, path-connected, etc.) and how it is typically applied. To start off, the way I learned about neighbourhoods (of a point) in class is that these are sets (not necessarily open) that contain an open set (containing the point). Accordingly, the definition of local Xness that I learned is "a space is locally X if every neighbourhood of every point contains an X neighbourhood" (there are no assumptions about the X neighbourhood being open). But when we say that every neighbourhood contains an X neighbourhood, we cannot expect said X neighbourhood to be open, can we?

Here is an example of what I mean by this and what is the source of my consternation: if we are studying covers of a locally connected space, it is then common to say "for each point, we can pick the evenly-covered neighbourhood to be connected" (by an evenly-covered neighbourhood of a point I mean an **open** set whose pre-image is a disjoint union of open sets each of which is homeomorphic to it), but how do we actually "pick" said connected evenly-covered neighbourhood? The point $x$ has an evenly-covered neighbourhood $U$ (open, by the definition of "evenly-covered"), which contains a connected neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ (by definition of local connectedness), but we cannot now say that $V$ is a connected evenly-covered neighbourhood of $x$, because we do not a priori know if it is open. And we can't really restrict to the interior of $V$ either, because it might not then be connected. This situation comes up time and time again when studying covers. Another example of this is when one says that locally X spaces have a basis of X sets. How does this mesh with my definition, when all we know is that X sets form local bases and we don't assume them to be open?

Of course, all of these problems disappear when we simply agree that neighbourhoods are open by definition, but what is one to do when one defines neighbourhoods more generally? Should one then define local Xness as "every neighbourhood contains an **open** X neighbourhood"?

Comment: I mean, don't you want to consider, for instance, local compactness? In most situations there is a complete dearth of compact open sets.

Comment: @Tyrone let's forget about local compactness for a minute (there's a bunch of different definitions that are not entirely equivalent if the space isn't Hausdorff), how does this work for locally connected or path-connected spaces?

Comment: The definition of 'locally $P$' that I am most familiar with is that each point has a (not necessarily open) neighbourhood with property $P$ (with the subspace/relative topology). Unless I've missed something, this should work for any topological property $P$, whether connectedness, compactness, whatever. The thing to look out for with different definitions is that sometimes these are equivalent only when $X$ is Hausdorff

Comment: @OliverHouse that is the definition I am familiar with as well. So how does one use it in the case of, for example, covers of locally-connected spaces to show connected evenly-covered neighbourhoods exist? We know that $U$ an evenly-covered neighbourhood must contain a connected neighbourhood $V$, but if we don't know if it's open, how can we say it is a connected evenly-covered neighbourhood (and if that's not how one shows the existence of a conn. ev-cov. NBD, how else does one do this?). Do we just agree then that "evenly-covered"="not necessarily open"?

Comment: (not forgetting about local compactness) as you point out, it is rare that there is one 'correct' definition that captures all phenomena you might like to study. I assure you the situation for connectedness is no different.

Comment: @Tyrone so you're suggesting the appropriate definition for the setting of covers is the ammended "every neighbourhood contains an open connected neighbourhood" one?

Comment: By definition, *appropriate* depends on the circumstances. I am suggesting that there is not one definition that is appropriate for all circumstances. I'm guessing that you are studying covering spaces, and then the definition you have just written seems appropriate. On the other hand, in Hausdorff continua, your definition is equivalent to being connected in kleinen at each point, and this latter notion may be a better starting point if you enjoy continua theory. I'm guessing that your definition al least solves the problems you highlight in your text.

Comment: @Tyrone 'In kleinen'... do you mean locally?

Comment: @OliverHouse a continuum $X$ is *connected in kleinen* at $x\in X$ if for each closed $A\subseteq X$ with $x\not\in A$, there is a subcontinuum $C\subseteq X$ with $x\in C^\circ\subseteq C\subseteq X\setminus A$.

Comment: @Tyrone Cool! :)

Comment: I have seemingly found a satisfying answer to my question elsewhere: in locally (path) connected spaces (according to my definition, i.e. NBDs contain (path) connected, not necessarily open, NBDs) (path) components of **open** sets are open (in the ambient space). That is, in the case of coverings one can simply take a (path) component of an evenly-covered set and get a (path) connected evenly-covered set. It also follows that there exists a basis of open (path) connected sets, since each open set is a union of its (path) components, which turn out to be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local connectedness (every neighbourhood $N$ of an arbitrary point $x$ has a neighbourhood $C_x$, so that $x \in C_x \subseteq N$ and $C_x$ is connected) is special in the sense that it is equivalent to saying that a component of an open subspace $O$ of $X$ is always open (in $O$ and hence in $X$ too). This is a classic fact.

This implies the fact about the covering $f: Y \to X$: if $N_x$ is an evenly covered neighbourhood of $x$, then let $O_x$ be the component of $\operatorname{int}(N_x)$ that contains $x$ and then $O_x$ is open connected and evenly covered too (as subset of $N_x$).

So we don't *demand* open connected neighbourhoods inside every neighbourhood but we get them for free by this theorem.

For local compactness (in the presence of Hausdorffness, which is the most common) the analogous definition (every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood of $x$) does *not* give open compact neighbourhoods, so in that sense the connectedness localisation is "special".

IIRC local path-connectedness has similar properties as local connectedness.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I had arrived at basically the same point through googling. Regarding local path-connectedness, as far as I can see is all of what you've stated for local connectedness should hold word for word.

Comment: @V.Ch. I think that’s the case and the proofs are almost the same too.